# How to understand "alone of everyone" in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> He made a small choking noise, then looked round at Kingsley and the man with short grey hair, who **alone of everyone** in the room had remained entirely silent so far.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I don't quite understand the grammar of "alone of everyone". It seems to say Kingsley stands away from everyone else in the room. Is "alone of" a collocation?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I thought you were asking about the meaning of the phrase. Upon looking more closely, I see it is a grammatical question, which I can't address in this case. I should have known that someone with that much rep would be able to understand the meaning of such a phrase. I was looking at the title of question, so I thought it was a meaning question.

Comment: @DonB. I'm still a learner, so I might simply misunderstand it. It's nice for you to explain its meaning. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's another way to phrase something like:

> Out of everyone in the room, **he alone** had remained silent so far.

Ngram suggests [this is not a very common phrase](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=alone%20of%20everyone%2C%20out%20of%20everyone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), at least relative to "out of everyone".  I can't say why Rowling chose to use it instead of the more common version, but it's a legitimate expression.